# ios File transfer by xmppframework

Tags: ios, xmpp, file-transfer

I use xep0096 and xep0065 complete file tansfer,and send file from spark to ios simulator.
openfire server setting:

```
xmpp.auth.anonymous true
xmpp.domain mydomain
xmpp.filetransfer.enabled true
xmpp.proxy.enabled true
xmpp.proxy.externalip 114.xxx.xxx.xxx
xmpp.proxy.port 7777
xmpp.proxy.transfer.required false
xmpp.session.conflict-limit 0
xmpp.socket.ssl.active true
```

Performed very well in front，but spark send activate xml info like this:

```
<iq id="da0Di-69" to="proxy.mydomain" type="set">
  <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_8730437306760952695">
    <activate>ios@mydomain/leestarxin</activate>
  </query>
</iq>
```

the server return

```
<iq id="da0Di-69" to="spark@mydomain/leestarxin" from="proxy.mydomain" type="error">
  <error code="405" type="CANCEL">
    <not-allowed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

I look up xep0065,and find the error 405:

```
<not-allowed/> if only one party (either Requester or Recipient, but not both) is connected to the Proxy
```

Why would return this error？who can help me? 
thank you!

additional:

I can receive callback

```
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
```

but can't get any data.

Comment: am also changed settings like above but i receive connection failed callback. can u explane please

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late and the question is old, but might help someone else. Look into the latest push into the `XMPPFramework` by `Jonathon Staff`. Link [here](http://jonathonstaff.com/tackling-file-transfers-with-the-xmppframework/)